# Javascript Cross Domain PostMessage not working

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

I have a page that opens a child window (having iframe) and from new page I am calling Parent function to pass some values from Child to parent window. 
Child Window Code:

```
 window.opener.ParentFunction(sendvalues);
```

Since both are in same domain (example.com)it is working fine for me.
Now because of some change I need to move my child window to a new domain (new.example.com). Nor i am getting Premission denied error.

In order to fix this I am using PostMessage.

Child window code:

```
window.parent.postMessage(sendvalues,"*");
```

Parent Code:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

var eventer = window[eventMethod];    

var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
//for debug    
alert(e.data);

ParentFunction(e.data);

}, false);
```

This is not working for me I am not getting any value. No error, nothing is happening.
The code is not getting executed in eventer method.I am not getting any alert.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just saw your usage of `postMessage` - can you expand on the details ...

Comment: @Jaromanda X..what details you are looking for..it seems code for eventer function is not getting called at all...I am not getting any alert which i added.

Comment: @Jaromanda X : So do i need to send PostMessage to popwindow from Parent window as well In my case it is not required as i am passing all values using query string, however from Child i want to pass value using Postmessage. Can it be done using "event.source.postMessage"

Comment: `parent.postMessage(obj, window.location.origin);` Set the domain and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: sorry about the stupid answer, but `window.parent.postMessage` or `window.opener.postMessage` should be working without issue - perhaps it's the code in the child that's wrong - show a bit more of that

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X, This is what i originally used and I am not able to get desirable result as posted in my original post. I am not at stand still not sure what should i try. From parent no need to send any message to child as mentioned in link [link]https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: @epascarello - isn't the second argument to postmessage the **destination** host, not the source host

Comment: @SamM - I can only apologise for my test earlier going wrong (still don't know why it wasn't working!) - can you confirm that the postMessage actually gets called?

Comment: function Save() {
                try {
                 var sendvalues = "Some values from multiple variable";
              window.parent.postMessage(sendvalues);                window.close();
           }
             catch(ex) {
                alert(ex.message);
             }
            } This is what my child code is. Save method is called on button click. in that i need to send values to parent. for this i am using postMessage.

Comment: also, am I reading it right ... there's the parent, a child and the child also has an iframe? - and the iframe is the source of the postMessage destined for the parent?

Comment: yes. Parent calls child which has an iframe and the iframe is the source of the postMessage destined for the parent. So in my Save method i added window.parent.postMessage(sendvalues,"*"); and remove Window.close. Still the same result :(

Comment: well, your iframe is posting the message to the child, not the parent. window.parent in the iframe is your child window, window.parent.opener is your parent window. Which domains are each of these three pages in? you have two in one domain, and one in another ... which two are in the same domain

Answer (score 1):

Based on new information, you should be calling:

> if the child and iframe are in the same domain

```
window.parent.opener.postMessage
```

> if the parent and child are in the same domain and the iframe isn't, the iframe may need to call

```
window.parent.postMessage
```

> and then, the child window should listen and pass on the message to the parent using

```
window.opener.postMessage
```

although, you could still try window.parent.opener.postMessage in this case - I'm not about to test everything for you ;)

Comment: That should work fine in Firefox (and other browsers).

Comment: @Jaromanda X : I tried what you suggested, Post a message from parent as well as Child, however it is not working for me.

Comment: In Child window, i need to send data to parent on click of Button.

Comment: See edited answer - `window.parent.postMessage` should be working without issue - I'm going to delete this stupid answer once I know you've seen it

Comment: @JaromandaX...I really appreciate you helping me out. As suggested i tried window.parent.opener.postMessage, Now i am getting error No such Interface Supported.

Comment: Which two pages are on the same domain. Out of parent child and iframe

Comment: Parent domain (say example.com) child and iframe (say new.example.com)...Also I tried setting both domain to same by forcing document.domain = "example.com", this works, however it is causing issue when i save Parent form.

Comment: Child is a popup?